# Unable to locate an element using class name - Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

HI I am new to Selenium and I am trying to solve one task .

Req is I need to goto the below website
https://www.credify.tech/phone/nonDMFunnel. I need to enter some number is loan amount and select loan purpose drop down .It is identified only with class name 
This is not identifying the drop down menu ..

please help how I should locate the Element

Thanks

```
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();   
      driver.get("https://www.credify.tech/phone/nonDMFunnel");
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      WebElement desiredAmt=driver.findElement(By.name("desiredAmount")); 
      desiredAmt.sendKeys("2000");
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.findElement(By.className("sc-fAjcbJ bvkLRg")).click();
    \\  Select mySelect = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(.,'Loan')]")));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use only one class name to select that element.

And add a wait condition for that element to be clickable.

This should work:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("sc-fAjcbJ"))).click();
```

instead of this line

```
driver.findElement(By.className("sc-fAjcbJ bvkLRg")).click();
```